# Python/Pandas - Combine multiple columns matching string name as single string col

Tags: python, pandas

My data set comes from jira and the Labels data is separated into multiple columns, one for each label in the row. This number of rows can vary from 1 to more than 5 depending on how many label tags were used on a given entry.

The csv could look like:

```
Issue Type  Issue key   Labels    Labels    Labels    Labels    Labels
Story       123         #label1,  #label2,  #label6,  #label7,  #label9,
Story       124                 
Story       125         #label3,  #label1,          
Bug         126                 
Story       127         #label5,
```

The number of columns can vary getting a new Labels column for every tag in the row. There seems to be no way to correct the export to enclose the values as a single string.

What I'm needing to do is concatenate these into a single column "Tags", and I don't care about cleaning up the trailing comma.

I've tried

```
df['Tags'] = [col for col in df.columns if 'Label' in col]
```

But this throws an error "Length of values does not match length of index"

Is there a simple way to accomplish this when reading the CSV into the dataframe?

Comment: kindly share ur expected output. dataframe form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `agg` function:

```
colums = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('value')]
df[columns].agg(lambda x : '-'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Comment: Nice, I have never aggregated on axis = 1 :)

Comment: This throws the error: 
TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @J.P. I edited the answer for not object type columns

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are really trying to do is:

```
tags = [col for col in df.columns if 'Label' in col]
nontags = [col for col in df.columns if 'Label' non in col]
tagdf = df[tags]
tagcol = tagdf.apply(" ".join, axis=1)
newdf = pd.concat([df[nontags], tagcol], axis = 1)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'join' is not defined - and .join is invalid syntax..

Comment: @J.P. It was a typo, which you should be able to fix in about 20 seconds.